# How to fix Html table in Markdown Text

Tags: html, markdown

I was fixing format issues of many Markdown files, which contain huge html formatted table which contain markdown formatted text like this:

[image: picture]

These html table contain lots of "**bold**" and "[title](link)"

I tried to use regular expression but there are still thousands mistakes remain, if possible, I don't want to change all **bold** to <b>bold</b>, nor change [title](link) to <a href="link">title</a>.

How can I fix these issues quickly?

Comment: By default, Markdown syntax is not parsed inside block level raw HTML tags. However, many implementations offer an option to change that behavior. However, each works slightly differently. Which are you using?

Comment: @Waylan, Thanks you. I'm just an editor, I can't decide how to parse Markdown syntax. All I can do is converting the markdown syntax in HTML tags to HTML format.

Comment: Yes, but if we know which tool you are using, then we can suggest syntax and or options specific to that tool you can use to better meet your needs.

Comment: I'm using VS code to edit these \*.md files, I've tried to use ">(.*)\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)(.*)<" and >(.*)\*\*(.*)\*\*(.*)< to match these Markdown syntax, but there are still tons of Markdown syntax remain. If possible, I don't want to use "\*\*(.*)\*\*" and "\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)" to replace all Markdown syntax. I'm trying to convert Markdown syntax only.